# Trouble in changing VARCHAR type to timestamp using ALTER in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ddl

[data set screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZllW.jpg)

I have used the code as below to change varying character to datetime, but had problem.

```
ALTER TABLE updated_runner_orders 
  ALTER COLUMN pickup_time 
   TYPE TIMESTAMP
     USING to_timestamp(pickup_time::timestamp);
```

Comment: Use `USING pickup_time::timestamp`.

Comment: That doesn't work as some of the entries in pickup_time column is empty.

Comment: Convert empty strings to nulls: `USING nullif(pickup_time, '')::timestamp`